# number of spanning tree of $K(3,5)$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

A spanning tree T of an undirected graph G is a subgraph that is a tree which includes all of the vertices of G, with minimum possible number of edges.
I need number of spanning tree of $K(3,5)$ where $k$ is bipartite complete graph.
Can you help me?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close with reading the comments.

Comment: I got $2025$ through a somewhat ad-hoc case analysis. Curiously, this equals $3^{5-1}5^{3-1}$ which might hint at a general formula.

Comment: After more ad-hoc analysis I'm now sure that $K_{n,m}$ has exactly $n^{m-1}m^{n-1}$ spanning trees _at least_ when $\min(n,m)\le 4$.

Comment: Are you familiar with the matrix-tree theorem?

Comment: @HenningMakholm, FWIW a search for *bipartite spanning trees* on OEIS turns up that formula and a bunch of references.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know [Kirchhoff's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_theorem)?  If you do, it is not very difficult.  Otherwise, you can find a combinatorial proof that $K_{m,n}$ has $m^{n-1}n^{m-1}$ spanning trees from this [paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-46908-4_38) (or [here](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-3-642-46908-4_38.pdf)).  I also found [another paper](http://www.austinmohr.com/15spring4980/paper%20final%20draft.pdf) with the proof of Kirchoff's theorem and a different proof of the same result.  In particular, for $(m,n)=(3,5)$, there are $3^{5-1}5^{3-1}=2025$ spanning trees of $K_{3,5}$.

WLOG, let the vertices of $K_{m,n}$ be $1,2,\ldots,m+n$.  The vertex bipartition is $$\{1,2,\ldots,m\}\cup\{m+1,m+2,\ldots,n\}.$$

Let $D$ be the degree matrix of 
$$D=\operatorname{diag}(\underbrace{n,n,\ldots,n}_{m\text{ copies}},\underbrace{m,m,\ldots,m}_{n\text{ copies}}).$$
We take $J_{p,q}$ to the $p\times q$ matrix all of whose entries are $1$.  Let $A$ be the adjacency matrix
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&J_{m,n}\\ J_{n,m}&0\end{pmatrix}.$$

The Laplacian matrix $L$ is given by $D-A$, so
$$L=\begin{pmatrix}nI_m&-J_{m,n}\\-J_{n,m}&mI_n\end{pmatrix}.$$
We must remove the last row and column of $L$ to get
$$Q=\begin{pmatrix}nI_m&-J_{m,n-1}\\-J_{n-1,m}&mI_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}.$$
The matrix $Q$ is an $(m+n-1)\times (m+n-1)$ matrix.  I claim that the eigenvalues of $Q$ are $1$, $n-1$ copies of $m$, and $m-1$ copies of $m$.

First, $$EQ=\begin{pmatrix}nI_m&-J_{m,n}\\0&-\frac{m}{n}J_{n-1,n-1}+I_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}$$
where 
$$E=\begin{pmatrix}I_m&0\\\frac{1}{n}J_{n-1,m}&I_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}.$$
Since $\det E=1$, we have
$$\det Q=\det(EQ)=\det (nI_m)\det\left(-\frac{m}{n}J_{n-1,n-1}+mI_{n-1}\right).$$
It is not difficult to see that 
$$\det\left(-\frac{m}{n}J_{n-1,n-1}+mI_{n-1}\right)=\frac{m^{n-1}}{n},$$
since $m$ is an eigenvalue of $-\frac{m}{n}J_{n-1,n-1}+mI_{n-1}$ with multiplicity $n-2$, and the other eigenvalue is 
$$\operatorname{Tr}\left(-\frac{m}{n}J_{n-1,n-1}+mI_{n-1}\right)-m(n-2)=\frac{m}{n}.$$
Thus,
$$\det Q=\det (nI_m)\det\left(-\frac{m}{n}J_{n-1,n-1}+mI_{n-1}\right)=n^m\left(\frac{m^{n-1}}{n}\right)=m^{n-1}n^{m-1}.$$
By Kirchhoff's theorem, there are $m^{n-1}n^{m-1}$ spanning trees of $K_{m,n}$.